# Creating two instances of mfupload

Tags: jquery

I have a problem. I used a plugin called mfupload, which is a jquery drag and drop file upload plugin.

http://www.jscripts.info/mfupload.php

To create an instance, I need to write this:

```
$('#upload').mfupload();
```

Now the problem starts when I need to create two instances of that.

```
$('#upload').mfupload();
$('#upload2').mfupload();
```

The plugin uses only the last instance as their working js code. I need a way to make the two instances work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to put it into two variables?

Comment: Hi, I'm relatively new here. Can teach me how?

Comment: I'm not sure about your case here. nut you can try 

var x = $('#upload').mfupload();   


var y = $('#upload2').mfupload();   

and see if it might help or not!!

Comment: Just post your answer then.

Comment: It would have been nice to post your solution so when people like me who have the same issue come across your question, we'd be set on the right track as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. change your code

`$('#upload').mfupload(); $('#upload2').mfupload();`

in to

```
$('#upload, #upload2').mfupload();
```

thank's